# Как найти закрывающий body и перед ним вставить JS?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь найти и заменить `</body>`

нужно перед `</body>` вставить JS, делаю так и получаю ошибку:

syntax error unexpected t_string, expecting ',' or ')'

в строке `Varible1: ["Emma", "Noah", "Olivia", "Liam", "Ava","William"],`

```
$response = str_ireplace('</body>', '

<!-- Fake Notifications invoke -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#notification-3').Notification({
            // Notification varibles
            Varible1: ["Emma", "Noah", "Olivia", "Liam", "Ava","William"],
            Varible2: ["Bangkok","London","Paris","Dubai","New York","Singapore"],
            Amount: [1000, 25000],                  
            Content: '[Varible1] from [Varible2] has just win $[Amount].',
            // Timer
            Show: ['random', 3, 10],
            Close: 7,
            // Notification style 
            LocationTop: [false, '5%'],
            LocationBottom:[true, '2%'],
            LocationRight: [false, '20px'],                     
            LocationLeft:[true, '10px'],
            Background: 'black',
            BorderRadius: 0,
            BorderWidth: 5,
            BorderColor: 'gold',
            TextColor: 'white',
            IconColor: 'gold',
            // Notification Animated   
            AnimationEffectOpen: 'rotateIn',
            AnimationEffectClose: 'zoomOut',
            // Number of notifications
            Number: 5,
            // Notification link
            Link: [false, 'https://codecanyon.net/user/wow-company/portfolio', '_blank']                
        }); 


    });             

</script>   

</body>', $response);
```

Comment: "делаю так и получаю ошибку" - никогда не говорите - какую.

Comment: syntax error unexpected t_string, expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: @Ипатьев, но ведь приведен код на php, и ошибка в нем же

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо экранировать одиночные кавычки в скрипте. На первой такой кавычке строка прерывается, и дальнейшее считается кодом.

```
    ...
    $(\'#notification-3\').Notification({
    ...
```

и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо! Я экранировал но не то.

Comment: @MicroRu Пожалуйста. Успехов!